# I need help (both with GRUB and GPU pass-through)

Tags: grub, kvm, qemu, gpu, pop-os

How do I add a parameter to system-d on Pop!_OS? I want to pass-through a GPU. Please also give a a good guide of how to GPU pass-through on Pop!_OS 21.10. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Unix & Linux StackExchange!

Please *edit your question* to add a link to the specific tutorial you're following, so that other people will be able to get an idea of the steps you are trying to follow.

My guess is, your tutorial is probably telling you to add some kernel boot parameters, which would typically go onto `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="..."` line in `/etc/default/grub` on Linux systems that use GRUB as their bootloader.

But Pop!_OS currently uses `systemd-boot` as its bootloader, instead of GRUB. Since the boot parameters are passed to the Linux kernel, the syntax of the parameters themselves will remain the same, but the way you tell the bootloader to pass specific parameters to the kernel will be somewhat different in every bootloader that is capable of booting Linux.

So the question you probably need to be asking is "how to add kernel boot parameters when using `systemd-boot`?"

And the answer to that question is: you add them to the `options` line in the appropriate `$BOOT/loader/entries/*.conf` file, where `$BOOT` might be `/boot`, `/efi` or even `/boot/efi` depending on where your distribution chooses to mount its UEFI ESP partition. You'll find more details about those `*.conf` files and their format in https://systemd.io/BOOT_LOADER_SPECIFICATION/ .

After a bit of Googling, it seems that Pop_OS specific names for these files would be something like:

```
/boot/efi/loader/entries/Pop_OS-current.conf
/boot/efi/loader/entries/Pop_OS-old-kern.conf
```

The first of those would be for the current kernel, the second is for an old kernel version that is kept as a backup in case something goes wrong with the newest kernel. I would recommend that you modify the first file only, and only make changes to the second file after you have tested the boot process with your modified options and are 100% sure it works.

Comment: Oh, so we use system-d boot. TY!

Comment: Actually what is the path to system-d like /etc/default/grub? Yes I want to add parameters.

Comment: Please read the last paragraph of my answer. I cannot give you the exact filename because it may include the machine ID that is unique to your computer. But you should find it as `/boot/loader/entries/*.conf` if the `/boot/loader` directory exists on your system, or as `/efi/loader/entries/*.conf` if the `/efi/loader` directory exists on your system.

Comment: Oh okay. So that is basically GRUB.

Comment: So is it `/boot/efi/loader/entries/Pop-OS_old-kern.conf` ?

Comment: From the filename, it looks like that file defines the options to use when booting Pop-OS with an old kernel version (to be used when your most recent kernel fails). There might be another `*.conf` file in the same directory for the *current* kernel. After a bit of Googling, it seems it might be `/boot/efi/loader/entries/Pop_OS-current.conf`. I recommend that you only edit the `Pop_OS-current.conf` and leave the `Pop_OS_old-kern.conf` unchanged, so you won't accidentally end up with an unbootable system if you make a mistake.